# can a directive modify the width of a child element using jqLite?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an directive that clones its target table element and then modifies the clone. I would like to change the width of rows (or cells) in the cloned table.

Using jqLite, the directive can set the table's width:

```
elem.css({width: 180+'px'});
```

Executing a similar statement on a row (or td) in the table gives 'TypeError: undefined is not a function':

```
row.css({ width: cellWidth+'px' });
```

This snippet of jQuery does exactly what I need:

```
var $fixedTable = fixedTable;
$fixedTable.find('tr').each(function (x, elem) {
    $(elem).find('th,td').each(function (i, elem) {
        $(elem).width(cellWidth);
    });
});
```

Can this be done using jqLite or do I need to use jQuery to change the row widths?

Comment: +1 I had same issue: "to modify the width of a child element in Angular directive". Your question pointed me right direction and it even contains answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

jqLite is a subset of jQuery. jqLite includes the find() method limited to lookups by tag name. I'd need to see more of your code, but if you're only using tags (tr, th, td, etc.) then you should be able to select the desired child elements using only jqLite. jqLite does not include the width() method you are using above. You could use addClass() as a work around, but you'd need to have a predefined width class. I hope this helps. There is an opinion that you should avoid jQuery with AnguarJS. You should be able to use jqLite easily, but that'd depend on the exact use case.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

**Angular's jqLite**
jqLite provides only the following jQuery methods:

- addClass()
- ...
- find() - Limited to lookups by tag name

Comment: The exact use case is to modify the width of a child element of the jqLite element. My question now includes the jQuery that accomplishes what I wanted to do in jqLite but could not because the css() method was undefined for the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is how you traverse through `elem` to the child (`row`), because

```
row.css({ width: cellWidth+'px' });
```

is correct. Probably you have to used something like:

```
row = elem.children(XY);
```

See [Angular's jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) docs for reference.